# Error in applying bert for multi class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, bert-language-model

I'm trying to apply https://github.com/xuyige/BERT4doc-Classification this: how to Fine-Tune BERT for Text Classification for multi-class classification.

I'm getting this error that I don't understand as I'm beginner can anyone suggest what's wrong with this?
I can upload more code if needed

```
# This provides a function to convert row to input features and label

def to_feature(text, label, label_list=label_list, max_seq_length=max_seq_length, tokenizer=tokenizer):
 
  example = classifier_data_lib.InputExample(guid = None,
                                            text_a = text.numpy(), 
                                            text_b = None, 
                                            label = label.numpy())
  feature = classifier_data_lib.convert_single_example(0, example, label_list,
                                    max_seq_length, tokenizer)
  
  return (feature.input_ids, feature.input_mask, feature.segment_ids, feature.label_id)

`

def to_feature_map(text, label):

  print(text)
  print(label)



  print("--------------------------------")
  input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_id = tf.py_function(to_feature, inp=[text, label], 
                                Tout=[tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64])
  print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
  

input_ids.set_shape([max_seq_length])
  input_mask.set_shape([max_seq_length])
  segment_ids.set_shape([max_seq_length])
  label_id.set_shape([])
  x = {
      'input_word_ids':input_ids,
      'input_mask':input_mask,
      'input_type_ids' : segment_ids
  }
  return(x, label_id)



with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  `# train

  train_dataf =(train_dataf.map(to_feature_map,
                                 num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                          .shuffle(1000)
                          .batch(16, drop_remainder=True)
                          .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))
 ` # valid

  val_dataf = (val_dataf.map(to_feature_map,
                            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                          .batch(16, drop_remainder=True)
                          .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)) `



`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-9288bc5628ca> in <cell line: 1>()
      2   # train
      3 
----> 4   train_dataf =(train_dataf.map(to_feature_map,
      5                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      6                           .shuffle(1000)

19 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _ExtractInputsAndAttrs(op_type_name, op_def, allowed_list_attr_map, keywords, default_type_attr_map, attrs, inputs, input_types)
    500             raise TypeError(f"{prefix} that don't all match.")
    501         else:
--> 502           raise TypeError(f"{prefix} that are invalid. Tensors: {values}")
    503 
    504       types = [x.dtype for x in values]

TypeError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-145-639c80d6eac1>", line 7, in to_feature_map  *
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_id = tf.py_function(to_feature, inp=[text, label],

    TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'input' of 'EagerPyFunc' Op have types [<NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>, int64] that are invalid. Tensors: [{'input_word_ids': <tf.Tensor 'args_2:0' shape=(32, 128) dtype=int64>, 'input_mask': <tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(32, 128) dtype=int64>, 'input_type_ids': <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=(32, 128) dtype=int64>}, <tf.Tensor 'args_3:0' shape=(32,) dtype=int64>]
```

I think there's something wrong with this

```
input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_id = tf.py_function(to_feature, inp=[text, label], 
                                Tout=[tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64])

  print(text)
  print(label)
#output for this line
{'input_word_ids': <tf.Tensor 'args_2:0' shape=(32, 128) dtype=int64>, 'input_mask': <tf.Tensor           args_0:0' shape=(32, 128) dtype=int64>, 'input_type_ids': <tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=(32, 128) dtype=int64>}
Tensor("args_3:0", shape=(32,), dtype=int64)
```